# Which versions of Final Fantasy VI include multiplayer battle support?

Tags: final-fantasy-6

I recall that Final Fantasy III US SNES included multiplayer battle support, where multiple players can control specific party members during battles. Through which versions/editions of Final Fantasy VI have multiplayer battle support and how many players are supported?

Comment: I... I don't remember that feature at all.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I guess it did check [this](http://img401.imageshack.us/img401/6028/beztytuucy9.jpg) and [this](http://img479.imageshack.us/img479/5002/beztytuu2yc9.jpg) out.

Comment: Are you referring only to SNES Final Fantasy games? There are quite a few Final Fantasy titles on various platforms that have elaborate multiplayer support (especially DS and PSP).

Comment: @sarmackie no, I'm referring to Final Fantasy 6 only. However I know there has been many versions of FF6 released through the years. Edited to make that intent clearer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both the SNES and PlayStation versions support this feature. It allows for a second player/controller to control party members in battle only.

Comment: That sounds right, the GBA edition doesn't have this feature.